# Create chemical equilibrium symbol in Katex

Tags: chemistry, katex

I'm trying to create this symbol in KaTex:

[image]

(I know there are the KaTex commands `\xrightleftharpoons{}` and `\rightleftharpoons`, but they make both arrows the same length.)

It's for an explanation  of [chemical equilibrium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_equilibrium).

best I managed is putting an arrow over an arrow:

```latex
\begin{array}{c}
   \scriptstyle exotherm\thinspace \thinspace \thinspace \thinspace\\
   H_2O + H_2O \thinspace \overleftharpoon{\thinspace\thinspace{\scriptscriptstyle\rightharpoondown} \thinspace\thinspace} \thinspace H_3O^+ + OH^-\\s
   \scriptstyle endotherm\thinspace \thinspace \thinspace \thinspace 
\end{array}
```

renders as (on https://katex.org/):

[image]

The problem is, I have no idea how to make the long arrow be on the bottom.
Is there a way to do this?
The function `\underleftharpoon{}` does not exist in KaTex.

*(I want to do this in KaTex, not MathJax)*

Comment: another attempt (works, but arrows are a little short):

```\begin{array}{c}
   \scriptstyle exotherm\thinspace \thinspace \thinspace \thinspace\\
   H_2O + H_2O \def\arraystretch{0.001}\begin{array}{c}\scriptscriptstyle\rightharpoonup\\\leftharpoondown\end{array} H_3O^+ + OH^-\\
   \scriptstyle endotherm\thinspace \thinspace \thinspace \thinspace 
\end{array}```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Katex](https://katex.org/docs/libs.html) provides the [mhchem extension](https://github.com/KaTeX/KaTeX/tree/main/contrib/mhchem) to write chemical equations.
According to their documentation for [reaction arrows](https://mhchem.github.io/MathJax-mhchem/#reactionarray) mhchem provides a stretched arrow functionality.

`$\ce{H2O + H2O <<=>[exotherm][sendotherm]H3O+ + OH-}$`

results in the following output:
[image]

Hope this helps. Otherwise the solution in your comment seems promising.